# Declare function for tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I'd like to declare a function that will be part of the equation that I then want to plot. The equation that I want to plot is defined as

```
\frac{e^{-rT}N'(d_{2})}{S\sigma\sqrt{T}}
```

The function to be declared is the probability density function

```
N'\left (x  \right )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}
```

where x should equal to `d_2`, and `d_2` must also be declared by

```
d_{2}=\frac{ln(S/K)+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}})
```

If possible I'd like to be able to define K, r and sigma in advance, so that they can flow into above calculation as fixed values. For the values of S (x axis) and T (y axis) I want to take a different domains, e.g. for S a range 95 to 105, and for T a range 0.01 to 0.3. The overall result should be a surfaceplot where the results of the intial equation are on the z axis. Thanks a million, I hope so much that somebody can help me!

ADDITION: the code that was provided by @percusse works very well but when I try to modify it following the logic of its structure I get an error. Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ Nprime(\x)                 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(pow(\x,2))); 
                   d1(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR+(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)  = - (exp(-\RR*\y)*d1*Nprime(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG))/(\y*(pow(\x,2))*(pow(\SIG,2))));
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[ y domain=0.01:0.3, domain=95:105,view={25}{20}, 
]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,y,100,0,0.09)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

ONE MORE ADDITION: I have tried to swap the \y and \SIG values. Here is the code that does not work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ Nprime(\x)                 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(pow(\x,2))); 
                   d2(\x,\SIG,\KK,\RR,\y)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\SIG,\KK,\RR,\y)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*Nprime(d2(\x,\SIG,\KK,\RR,\y))/(\x*\SIG*sqrt(\y));
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[
y domain=0.01:0.09, domain=95:105, view={25}{20}, 
]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,SIG,100,0,0.04)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fear that your aim is definitely not possible : in general  the elaborate LaTeX formulas cannot be parsed by the pgf engine. Just as an example, there is not `\frac` and your denominator would be writen as `\S*\sig*sqrt(\T)` provided that you have `\def`-ined the values of `\S`,`\sig` and `\T` (note te absence of \ before `sqrt` to {evaluate} de square root !

Comment: can you provide some values of the constants?

Comment: K = 100, r = 0, sigma = 0.09

Comment: the thing is, that I have that graph in matlab and I've tried to use matlab2tikz to transform the matlab-figure to latex. matlab2tikz does it with some distrotion, i.e. it simply chops off a part of the graph and places that piece arbitrarily somewhere else

Comment: @ajafarov You are missing the arguments of d1

Comment: @percusse ..... yes.... you are so right.. now it is working, thanks))

Comment: @percusse Could you figure out what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are simply replacing the name of the variables. that's not what you should do. Only change the order of the arguments of myfun in the declaration nothing else.

Comment: @percusse I am sorry but I get an error :( I have changed the order only in the myfun {\x, \SIG, \KK, \RR, \y} and I get an error

Comment: what is the error? Take the code in my answer and replace the line with `myfun(\x,\SIG,\KK,\RR,\y)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*Nprime(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG))/(\x*\SIG*sqrt(\y));` and it works (tested on writelatex).

Comment: @percusse Now it works! I am very grateful for your help and sorry for bothering you so much, my experience in working with latex is very very poor.. thank you once again!

Comment: @ajafarov My pleasure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know what it should look like but from the constants you have provided I get this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ Nprime(\x)                 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(pow(\x,2))); 
                   d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*Nprime(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG))/(\x*\SIG*sqrt(\y));
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[y domain=0.01:0.3,domain=95:105,view={150}{20}]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,y,100,0,0.09)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OH LA LAAAAA that is exactly what I need! You guys are simply Latex-Gods!!! Is it possible to replace the axis in the sense, that I get the 0-0.3 domain on the right hand side, and the 96-104 at the left hand side, simply replace them?

Comment: @ajafarov You can rotate the 3D view angles with `view` option added to the axis options. Replace it with `view={25}{20}`.

Comment: @ajafarov My pleasure. Next time please provide some more data and a MWE if possible. Writing the code from scratch is really not fun.

Comment: when I try to slightly modify the code that you have written today in order to make it suitable for another application I get an error: PGF Math: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near..." could you please help me? why is it the case?

Comment: I have edited the question and made an addition incl. code

Comment: Hi! I have a question with respect to your code, the values for \KK, \RR and \SIG are fixed and the values of \x and \y are variable. How can I make \KK, \RR and \y fixed and make \x and \SIG now variable? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ajafarov I haven't tested but swap the places of the arguments such that \SIG becomes the second argument?

Comment: I have tried it. I have basically let everything remain constant and changed only the following part \addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,0.04,100,0,SIG)}; then I tried the same and have put the backslash in front of SIG. Both attempts ended with errors :(

Comment: @ajafarov No I mean in the declaration of functions not the actual usage.

Comment: I have edited the initial problem and provided the code with swapped values in the declaration of functions. No success.

Comment: I wanted to ask you whether in context of the functions that you have been declaring you could define the function for a cumulative normal distribution? I have found this function: \tikzset{
    declare function={
        normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    }
} but it ends up with error. Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: @ajafarov Post a new question. It would be more visible.