# Declaration of cumulative distribution function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a code that illustrates a certain figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ Nprime(\x)                 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(pow(\x,2))); 
                   d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*Nprime(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG))/(\x*\SIG*sqrt(\y));
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[y domain=0.01:0.3,domain=95:105,view={150}{20}]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,y,100,0,0.09)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Instead of `Nprime(\x)` I would like to declare and integrate a cumulative distribution function `N(\x). A very close approximation of cumulative distribution function would also be fine. Everything else should remain equal. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks in advance!!!
Here is the formula: [enter link description here](http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue13/rb13_1.gif)
Something similar is provided here [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/how-to-draw-cdf-of-normal-distribution-in-tikz) but I dont know how to integrate is according to my needs :(

Here is a modified version that doesn't work. The last part of the function, i.e. (\x*\SIG*sqrt(\y)) was removed because it is not needed in this case. Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ normcdf(\x,\m,\s)          = 1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));; 
                   d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*normdcf(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG))
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[y domain=0.01:0.3,domain=95:105,view={150}{20}]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,y,100,0,0.09)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you also include the function (either the formula or a link) since not everybody here is mathematically specialized?

Comment: @percusse I have edited it, thanks for help!

Comment: Well you have the exact code given in the linked question what is the problem?

Comment: @percusse I have difficulties integrating it into the code written by you, that's my problem

Comment: What exactly are you trying to plot (`myfun` and `d2` aren't very enlightening function names)? Could you provide a link to a Wolfram Alpha plot of the desired function?

Comment: @Jake the code was initially written by percusse, he has established these definitions

Comment: @Jake but it all has to do with the pricing of financial derivatives, to be more precise options

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're talking about http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124878/2552. It seems to me like you provided the names `N'` and `d_2`, and didn't explain what the first function does, hence percusse's choice of `myfun`. Anyway, what do you mean with "difficulties integrating it into the code"? If you take the definition of `normcdf` and plug it into your code, do you get an error message? Or is the result not what you expected?

Comment: @Jake I didnt explain it, you're right. I used the function declared by you from the topic that I have linked, and I have replaced Nprime by normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s)); As a result I had an error, if you want, I can integrate it in accordance with my needs and show you the whole code, should I?

Comment: @ajafarov: Yes, I think that would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. Missing semicolon at the end of the definition of `myfun`. All functions defined using `declare function` have to end with a semicolon.
2. Typo in the function name (it's `normcdf`, not `normdcf`).
3. Incorrect call of the `normcdf` function. It takes three parameters: The x value, the mean, and the standard deviation of the normal distribution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ normcdf(\x,\m,\s)          = 1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
                   d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)     = (ln(\x/\KK)+(\RR-(pow(\SIG,2)/2)*\y))/(\SIG*(sqrt(\y)));
                   myfun(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG)  = exp(-\RR*\y)*normcdf(d2(\x,\y,\KK,\RR,\SIG),0,1);
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[y domain=0.01:0.3,domain=95:105,view={210}{20}]
\addplot3[surf] {myfun(x,y,100,0,0.09)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```